# After applying the theme to Dialog, no title is shown

Tags: android

I have a dialog with a title. When not using a theme, it works:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setTitle("My dialog");
```

But after I apply a theme, it no longer displays the title, and I cannot figure out why.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog);
dialog.setTitle("My dialog");
```

Comment: it appears to be a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79097).

Comment: What if you use a DialogFragment?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `DialogBuilder` :

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog);
builder.setTitle("Dialog");
```

Comment: Though not an answer, it's a good hint. I checked the source for `AlertDialog`, and they actually hide the default title and use custom view for title. Maybe I'll go that way too, to avoid problems...